# Rails: pair values from loop array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to pair the open-close hours of each store by the day. Fore example if Wednesday has two different open-close hours I would like to show them together under the Wednesday. Currently I'm doing the following which is returning everything separately... if Wednesday has two open-close hours the open-close hours show separately as two Wednesdays. Any idea on how to implement this?

@open_hours = OpenHour.where(store_id: params[:store_id]).order('day ASC')

```
    <% @open_hours.each do |open| %>
      <% if open.day == 1 %>
        <p><strong>Monday:</strong>
          <%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %>-<%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %></p>
      <% end %>
      <% if open.day == 2 %>
        <p><strong>Tuesday:</strong>
          <%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %>-<%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %></p>
      <% end %>
      <% if open.day == 3 %>
        <p><strong>Wednesday:</strong>
          <%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %>-<%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %></p>
      <% end %>
      <% if open.day == 4 %>
        <p><strong>Thursday:</strong>
          <%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %>-<%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %></p>
      <% end %>
      <% if open.day == 5 %>
        <p><strong>Friday:</strong>
          <%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %>-<%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %></p>
      <% end %>
      <% if open.day == 6 %>
        <p><strong>Saturday:</strong>
          <%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %>-<%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %></p>
        <% end %>
      <% if open.day == 0 %>
        <p><strong>Sunday:</strong>
          <%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %> -<%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %></p>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `@open_hours` are sorted in day order. Test to see if the previous open was for the same day, and if so skip the day name. Use a table to get alignment.

```
<% last_day = nil %>
<% days = %w(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday) $>
<table>
  <% @open_hours.each do |open| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= days[open.day] if open.day != last_day %>
        <% last_day = open.day%>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= I18n.l open.opens, :format => :custom %>-<%= I18n.l open.closes, :format => :custom %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use `Date::DAYNAMES` instead of `days`.